# Wrap an exe in an MSI

Tags: windows-installer, exe, word-wrap

All,

How can I create an MSI file that extracts an EXE file to a temporary directory and runs it with options same as were passed to the EXE file?

Thanks very much for your guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

The MSI has [native support for custom actions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066(v=vs.85).aspx), using this you can launch your EXE. But how to exactly configure this depends on the [tool you choose to build your MSI.](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm)

Which one are you using?